# Wordpress woocomerce graphql failing

Tags: graphql, gatsby

After importing lots of products to my WordPress Woocomerce store, GraphQL started to fail. Anyone know how I can fix this problem?

```
ERROR #gatsby-source-wordpress_111007 

gatsby-source-wordpress  Request failed with status code 500

Your WordPress server is either overloaded or encountered a PHP error.

Enable WordPress debugging by adding the following to your wp-config.php file:

define("WP_DEBUG", true);
define("WP_DEBUG_LOG", true);
define("GRAPHQL_DEBUG", true);

(See https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/ for more info)

Then run another build before checking your WordPress instance's debug.log file for errors.

If you don't see any errors in debug.log:

Try reducing the requestConcurrency for content updates or the previewRequestConcurrency for previews, and/or
reducing the schema.perPage option:

{
  resolve: 'gatsby-source-wordpress',
  options: {
    schema: {
      perPage: 20, // currently set to 100
      requestConcurrency: 5, // currently set to 50
      previewRequestConcurrency: 2, // currently set to 5
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you used `perPage` as suggested? Is the `gatsby-source-wordpress` your configuration or it's an example?

Comment: Its my configuration, i've used many different configurations but none of them seems to be working.

Comment: Can you provide them? Is the gatsby-source-wordpress your configuration or it's an example?

Comment: It doesn't matter what number i put in the schema i still get the error. The problem lies somewhere else i think.

Comment: I still don't know what configuration do you have so I'm not able to ensure if the error is here or somewhere else. There are 2 lines of description and 50 of code. Try to provide as much information as possible, please...

Comment: Im using gatsby with wordpress as cms. To fetch data WP-graphql and wp-graphql-woocomerce.

Comment: eh, try to provide some non-obvious info ... like [shared] hosting specs/limits/cpu/ram usage/stats during data fetching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allocating more memory to wordpress fixed the issue.

Add this line to wp.config file.

```
define( ‘WP_MEMORY_LIMIT’, ‘512M’ );
```